# Disable automatic content hyperlinking

Tags: links, content, visual-editor, automation

How can I prevent WordPress from converting links in my page content into hyperlinks?

For example if I write http://www.test.com I don't want it converted to a link.

Comment: Please specify the version of wordpress you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress does not automatically convert URLs to hyperlinks.

Comment: It must be some plugin I have then :S I will have to track it down

Comment: Today is 2015, and it does now.

Answer (score 2):

It's the Editor TinyMCE's embed plugin
to disable it you will also need to disable all other embeds (twitter, images, youtube, etc)

If you still want to proceed, then enter this code in your theme's functions.php

```
function disable_embeds_code_init() {
wp_deregister_script('wp-embed');
 add_filter( 'tiny_mce_plugins', 'disable_embeds_tiny_mce_plugin' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'disable_embeds_code_init', 11 );
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable the autolinking(embedding) on just a specific link. Switch from visual to text and wrap the link in a `<span>`. Careful though, if you toggle back to visual it will remove the span and embed again. So if you have other content there get that all done first and then add the span when you are done.